# How to view html output in Notepad++?

Tags: editor, notepad++

How do I view my Code output in Notepad++ as a webpage or something similiar?

I have built something but I can't find a button or something like that in Notepad to view it as a webpage or something similiar.

Comment: When you say review, do you mean post ? you want the code that you have in notepad++ posted to a web page ?

Comment: I think he wants to view his written HTML code in a browser. If correct: NP++ isn´t an IDE, but you could look through the "Run" menu

Comment: In most C-like languages, method calls consist of a method name and a parameter list, with the list enclosed in `(...)`.  If there are no parameters then `()` with noting in-between is specified.

Comment: (BTW, if you have a new question, start a new question.  Don't edit an old question to be entirely different.)

Comment: Is your code entirely in HTML, along with CSS/JavaScript or do you have server side code (PHP/Java) also?

Comment: Same doubt for me too. I can run my html code in TextPad/EditPlus (don't remember which one I used last time) by pressing the keyboard shortcut "Ctrl+B" which shows the output in another tab of  TextPad/EditPlus similar to a web browser. Is there an option to do the same in Notepad++ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is a webpage written in html: 
just go where you saved it and click it.

If it is in php:

You will need a web server, save the file in the www directory. and access it like this:

```
http://localhost/yourfile.php
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply, save your file with the correct extension in this case html, then click run , in the run menu click launch in, (in whichever is your browser) in my case, chrome.And it should work(:

Answer (score 1):

Add this plugin in Notepad++: [Preview HTML](https://fossil.2of4.net/npp_preview/home) but it opens only in IE

Answer (score 0):

**To setup Notepad++ for testing your markup or code there are a few things to consider.**

1. When Notepad++ launches do you want a test document opened by default?
2. What language do you prefer the document to be opened as?
3. What browser do you wish to test your test file in?
4. Do we want a shortcut to open test in browser?

If you do not have your local environment setup to run server-side scripts you will be limited to what the browser supports.

In my example setup I will be using `.php` as my language. There are some variables, but I've chosen what I believe best suit my needs. I'm also using a windows machine.

- Create a new file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++` (or wherever) as `php.php` (or whatever). *This will be the document we keep open and will remain open so long as we never close it.*
- In Notepad++ go to `Settings > Preferences > New Document`
- In the bottom left there is a drop-down. Select your language (php in my case).
- Open `php.php` in Notepad++.
- Go to `Run > Modify Shortcut / Delete Command` and locate your desired browser (*note: this may not work as expected in some browsers i.e. Internet Explorer, go figure*).
- Create a custom shortcut so your document can be launched to test (*unless you are happy with what is already setup*).

This will effectively keep your default file open in Notepad++ every time it is launched in your preferred language and allow you to quickly test your markup.

Answer (score 0):

Cntrl + Alt + Shift + I(Alphabet if you want to open in Internet explorer)

I hope this will work.